# function to scrape page keywords , description and title?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

i wrote simple 3 functions to scrape titles , description and keywords of simple html page
this is the first function to scrape titles

```
function getPageTitle ($url)
{
    $content = $url;
    if (eregi("<title>(.*)</title>", $content, $array)) {
        $title = $array[1];
        return $title;
    }
}
```

and it works fine
and those are 2 functions to scrape description and keywords and those not working

```
function getPageKeywords($url)
{
    $content = $url; 
    if ( preg_match('/<meta[\s]+[^>]*?name[\s]?=[\s\"\']+keywords[\s\"\']+content[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>/i', $content, $array)) { 
        $keywords = $array[1];  
        return $keywords; 
    }  
}
function getPageDesc($url)
{
    $content = $url; 
    if ( preg_match('/<meta[\s]+[^>]*?name[\s]?=[\s\"\']+description[\s\"\']+content[\s]?=[\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>/i', $content, $array)) { 
        $desc = $array[1];  
        return $desc; 
    }  
}
```

i know there may be something wrong with the preg_match line but i really don't know
i tried it so much things but it doesn't work

Comment: Just a note: `eregi` is deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML falls over at anything more complex than a simple tag pair; when you try to start parsing tag attributes, you need to switch to PHP Dom: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php The prob there is that the name, description and content attributes have to be in the order you are matching against.

Comment: third important point, just because it's on a web paged does not mean you have the rights do use the data any way you like (with out permission.

Comment: have you tried [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)? it's like jQuery DOM parsing.

Comment: [Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) is coming to get you... and he HUNGERS.

Comment: @Sp4cecat i tried it but i think its only parsing the structure between the <body> </body> tages only

Comment: @William Van Rensselaer i know but its my only choice i think

Comment: @Dagon im using this app for my own pages not to scrap information from other pages

Comment: @Marco refresh your page I answered 1 min ago...;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use get_meta_tags? [PHP Documentation Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php)

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```

**NOTE** You can change the parameter to either a URL, local file or string.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use php's native [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse HTML then regex, you can also use , tho in this day in age allot of sites dont even add the keywords, description tags no more, so you cant rely on them always being there. But here is how you can do it with DOMDocument:

```
<?php 
$source = file_get_contents('http://php.net');

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

//Get Title
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$description = '';
$keywords = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $metas) {
    if($metas->getAttribute('name') =='description'){ $description = $metas->getAttribute('content'); }
    if($metas->getAttribute('name') =='keywords'){    $keywords = $metas->getAttribute('content');    }
}

print_r($title);
print_r($description);
print_r($keywords);
?>
```